# Why does Selenium suddenly skips all my tests?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e

I'am used to run the **E2E** test couple of times a day during development... Today It suddenly skips all my test and all my spec files **`register.e2e-spec.ts`**

I didn't do any changes or updates on my spec files. The only thing was upgrade of nodeJs globally from **`8.x`** to **`10.0.0`**

Here is the output suddenly:

> webpack: Compiled successfully.
>   [10:44:40] I/update - chromedriver: file exists /Users/userName/demoapp/30_04/test-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.38.zip
>   [10:44:40] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.38.zip
>   [10:44:41] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /Users/userName/demoapp/30_04/test-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.38
>   [10:44:41] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.38 up to date
>   [10:44:41] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>   [10:44:41] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
>   [10:44:42] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.0.33:4444/wd/hub
>   Jasmine started
>
> Executed 0 of 7 specs INCOMPLETE (7 SKIPPED) in 0.015 sec.
>   [10:44:44] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
>   [10:44:44] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
>   [10:44:44] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
>   userName@User-MBP.xxxx.box:~/demoapp/30_04/test-app$

Comment: Where is the relevant CODE?

Answer (score -1):

Use `expect(true).toEqual(true);` in the end of your test.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this does, and why it might have caused Selenium to skip the tests in the first place?